# Iterate through rows in excel spreadsheet and find the difference in time when values in a different column are zero

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, python-datetime

This code iterates through an excel spreadsheet and finds a specific column where energy is zero, then calculates the duration of that zero-energy-value period by calculating difference between first & last appearance of the continuous zero values.

The problem I'm experiencing is: when there are multiple back-to-back rows of zero, the code stalls and never provides an output.

I'm finding it difficult to pinpoint where the issue is. Can I get some help with this?
Here is the sample data in the excel file. The issue is getting an output when we have more than a couple rows of zeroes. Note: Energy is in column 11, Start date is in column 3, and end date is in column 5 in the actual excel file as depicted in the code.

| Start Date | End Date | Energy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 10:54 | 1/1/2023 11:56 | 60 |
| 1/1/2023 13:28 | 1/1/2023 13:35 | 0 |
| 1/1/2023 19:02 | 1/1/2023 19:30 | 0 |
| 1/1/2023 21:03 | 1/1/2023 21:20 | 0 |
| 1/1/2023 21:35 | 1/1/2023 21:56 | 0 |
| 1/1/2023 22:23 | 1/1/2023 22:25 | 0 |
| 1/2/2023 08:34 | 1/2/2023 08:56 | 0 |
| 1/2/2023 09:04 | 1/1/2023 09:16 | 0 |
| 1/2/2023 09:14 | 1/2/2023 09:23 | 0 |
| 1/2/2023 10:05 | 1/2/2023 10:17 | 53 |

```
import datetime
import openpyxl
import collections
from itertools import islice

#import pandas
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

cpsd = ("Excel file")
cpsd_op = openpyxl.load_workbook(cpsd)
cpsd_s1 = cpsd_op['Session-2024']
cpsd_dcfc1 = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet_dcfc1 = cpsd_dcfc1["Sheet"]

# ^ pulls excel file in, we want to use openpyxl over pandas for excel, since it takes less time
# cpsd = session data

max_col_og = cpsd_s1.max_column
max_row_og = cpsd_s1.max_row
max_col_nw = sheet_dcfc1.max_column
max_row_nw = sheet_dcfc1.max_row
print(max_row_og, max_col_og)

for i in range(1, max_col_og+1):
    c = cpsd_s1.cell(row = 1, column= i)
    sheet_dcfc1.cell(row=1, column=i).value = c.value


for i in range(1, max_col_og+1):
        cell_obj = sheet_dcfc1.cell(row=1, column=i)
        print(cell_obj.value)

def del_empt_row (sheet):
    index_row = []
    for i in range(1, sheet.max_row):
        # define emptiness of cell
        if sheet.cell(i, 1).value is None:
            # collect indexes of rows
            index_row.append(i)

    # loop each index value
    for row_del in range(len(index_row)):
        sheet.delete_rows(idx=index_row[row_del], amount=1)
        # exclude offset of rows through each iteration
        index_row = list(map(lambda k: k - 1, index_row))


for j in range(1, max_row_og +1):
    for i in range(1, max_col_og +1):
        c = cpsd_s1.cell(row=j, column=1)
        if (c.value == "PP/ Charger 2"):
            k = cpsd_s1.cell(row=j, column=i)
            sheet_dcfc1.cell(row=j, column=i).value = k.value
            #print(k.value)

del_empt_row(sheet_dcfc1)

def enddate (sheet, row):
    #returns the end date of the last row with energy = 0
    for row2 in range(row, max_row_og + 1):
        if (sheet.cell(row=row2, column=10).value != 0):
            return [sheet.cell(row=row2-1, column=5).value,row2-1]
        else:
            enddate(sheet,row+1)

def consume(iterator, n):
    #allows us to skip the energy = 0 rows that have already been counted, since python is weird about iteration skipping
    #"Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)


zero_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00)
tot_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00)
#print(tot_time)

range_x = enumerate(sheet_dcfc1.iter_rows())
for row_num, row in range_x:
# calculates total time for t-outage provided that there are no empty rows.
    print(row_num)
    if (row[9].value == 0):
        strt_date = row[2].value
        print(strt_date)
        strt_row = row_num
        end_date_arr = enddate(sheet_dcfc1,row_num+1)
        end_date = end_date_arr[0]
        print(end_date)
        time = end_date-strt_date
        consume(range_x, end_date_arr[1]-strt_row)
#        print(row_num)
        #print(str(row) + "does row change?")
        tot_time += time

#        print(time)

print(tot_time-zero_time)
# prints total time for t-outage provided that there are no empty rows.
```

Comment: Can you provide the minimum example of the excel file's structure where this issue happens? (And with code for that example hopefully) Without that no one's gonna know for sure but to give speculative assumptions!  You can attach images to StackOverflow by simple ctrl+v in editor, or you could convert to CSV and write those as text here.

Comment: Hi, just want to clarify your question. Are you asking for the excel files format? as in, how many columns and rows?

Comment: Yes, it's for excel sheet format/structure as text & code alone won't visualize much about it. Number of columns and rows are totally up to you. As long as it reproduce issue you're facing, smaller the better! Not to forget updating code so that it can be ran with that simplified sheet! Many people can find issue themselves while undergoing that simplifying process, too!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've included a sample table.

Comment: Nice! So that file was enough to recreate issue you're having, right? Would've been even nicer to update code to only include absolute necessary parts that works over that example! For i.e. copying cells to other new `Workbook`, parts where empty rows are deleted(example contains no empty row!), or what is `PP/ Charger 2`, etc - such unclear parts are better be removed *Unless* is absolutely necessary. If so, writing even more detailed comment why that part is needed will help others identify issue in your code faster (and you could find it yourself during that process!)

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to add error traceback when program crashes!

Answer (score 1):

It would also be helpful to include some comments in code to explain what each section does.

From what I see working through the code, you are first adding the Headers from your original Sheet 'Session-2024' to a new Workbook Sheet `sheet_dcfc1` with name 'Sheet' (then reading back / printing these headers).

Next follows a loop looking for a cell with value "PP/ Charger 2"
There is no mention of this part in your post and the table provided does not include columns/rows with this value. Also the loop is wrong.

```
for j in range(1, max_row_og +1):
    for i in range(1, max_col_og +1):
        c = cpsd_s1.cell(row=j, column=1)
        if (c.value == "PP/ Charger 2"):
            k = cpsd_s1.cell(row=j, column=i)
            sheet_dcfc1.cell(row=j, column=i).value = k.value
```

You are setting j to count the rows in the origin worksheet and i to count the columns then the line `c = cpsd_s1.cell(row=j, column=1)` . So this means it always looks in the same column (A) due to 'column=1'. Presumably this should be 'column=i' 
If this is changed, then you're now looking in every cell from A1 to K11 (using your example data table). Is this value, "PP/ Charger 2" expected to be randomly in any column including those you have provided data for? If it is expected to be in a specific column then you should iterate just that column and not the whole used range. Please provide details on what/where/when of this value, as its existence seems important to the next sections. Without it the new worksheet will just contain the headers.

If the previous section does find that "PP/ Charger 2" value it copies that value to the **same** cell in the new Sheet. 
The code then runs a delete which seems aims to remove empty rows given that presumably "PP/ Charger 2" could be on any row. While this delete achieves that it also removes the Headers previously written.
If it is only necessary write that value once down the Sheet for each occurrence in the original Sheet then maybe use Openpyxl 'append' so each will be written to the next unused row. Either way this value can be added to the new sheet row by row without the need to then delete empty rows. The exact implementation would depend on where this text is expected to be found and how it should be written to the new Sheet.

Then the code loops a list of all cells in all rows looking specifically in column index 9 for a value of 0, `row[9].value == 0):` 
Presumably this is looking for the 0 value in the Energy column. However you state *Energy is in column 11* or Column 'K' whereas row[9] is Column 'J'. And again why select the whole range and not just loop through Column K only?
Then the code looking for a value of 0, but this is the new Sheet `range_x = enumerate(sheet_dcfc1.iter_rows())` , 'sheet_dcfc1' and all you have written to it is the Headers and the value "PP/ Charger 2" when it occurs, and then deleted the headers. There are no cells with a value of 0 ...
It seems may be when you find the value "PP/ Charger 2" it's the whole row you want to copy across, not just that cell?

You need to better explain what your code is supposed to do, what the expected result should be.